# Outlook VBA Sort by Date

Tags: arrays, vba, search, outlook, find

I am building a code that does a search in a Outlook folder and put the body of the items together in just one item (to build a history for that case).

I am performing the search using the Find method (not sure if all correct). Once I get the search results, I'll put them in an array.

Is there a way to sort the array by date? I keep getting an error with code below:

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olItms As Outlook.Items
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim MyArray() As String


Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace(”MAPI”)
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = olFldr.Items


Set olMail = myTasks.Find("[Subject] = ""*140115LS*""")
  If Not (olMail Is Nothing) Then

MyArray = olMail.Display
```

Comment: Did you mean `olItms.Find(...)` and not `myTasks.Find(...)` ?

Comment: Ohh yes, I changed the variable a few minutes ago! Tks!
Any thoughts on how can I sort it by date?

Answer (score 2):

```
'...
Dim sFilter as string
sFilter = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:mailheader:subject"" like '%140115LS%' "

Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Set olItms = olFldr.Items
Set olMail = olItms.Find(sFilter)

Do While Not olMail Is Nothing
    'add to array...

    Set olMail = olItms.FindNext
Loop
'...
```

Comment: This will not work - every time you call olFldr.Items, you get back a brand new COM object with no knowledge of the previous instances. You end up calling FindNext on a difference instance of the Items object. You need to cache the Items collection in a separate variable just as the original poster does.

Answer (score 0):

Call `olItms.Sort("[ReceivedTime]")` before calling Find. You will also need to call FindNext in a loop until it returns null.

Comment: I think you mean: olItms.Sort("[ReceivedTime]")... ReceivedDate is not a property in outlook 2013. (But maybe it was in previous versions)

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is ReceivedTime. I updated he answer.